# Can I share labels within Google Apps for Business?

Tags: google-workspace, gmail-labels

Can I **share labels** (= emails with particular labels) across Google Apps for Business users?

I have created a label called “testing” and I want to share the emails that have this label with other team members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're applying labels to the email based on a certain condition, you could edit the existing filter which applies the label to forward the email to your team members.

Comment: Might be a solution but as a last instance one. Sharing would be better. The other team members would have to setup their filters and labels....

Comment: there's no other way, to my knowledge. @Radek

Comment: I thought so but I better ask here :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily share synchronized Gmail labels with [SquadMail](https://www.squadmail.com/)

The labels look and feel like any other Gmail label except that they are always the same for all collaborators and will also show up in your team members' inboxes.

Additionally, each label gets its own email address and you can also synchronize your labels with Dropbox and automatically extract attachments that way.